# Python- Avoid automatic logging of udaexec in log file

Tags: python, linux, module, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

**Code:-**

```
    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="appname", version="1.0",logConsole=False,configureLogging=False)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info("Data loading into Teradata Successfull")
```

**udaexec.ini**

```
 [CONFIG]
    appName=TDDB
    version=2
    logConsole=False
    logLevel=debug
    dataSourceName=TDPROD
    configureLogging=False
```

I would like to get rid of automatic log generated from **udaexec** and want to log only in customized way like **logger.info("Data loading into Teradata Successfull")**.

Don't want below logs

```
   2020-01-09 03:04:23,314:teradata.udaexec:INFO:Connection successful. Duration: 0.224 seconds. Details:
```

**Edit post**

I am getting below error while installing teradatasql package

```
pip install teradatasql
Collecting teradatasql
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement teradatasql (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for teradatasql
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: If you don't want to see INFO level messages, you can set logLevel to CRITICAL, ERROR, or WARNING. There's no provision in the `teradata` module to entirely disable logging. You could consider using current `teradatasql` package instead of old `teradata`.

Comment: Fred, I have edited my post with latest error. Could you please help

Comment: teradatasql requires 64-bit Python 3.x

Comment: Actually Python >=3.4 (but it has to be 64-bit not 32-bit). https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/